# Using commands inside scripts for Perl?

Tags: perl, input, scripting, output, primes

I trying to run a perl command inside a script and here is what I got:

filenumber1.txt:

```
94088076164765675
```

The command window looks okay:

C:\Users\Guest\Documents\Prime Numbers>perl -Mntheory=:all -nE "chomp; say next_prime($_);" filenumber1.txt

94088076164765687

I am trying to do this in a script as well called primenumbers.pl and generate another file called log.txt as the output file and filenumber1.txt as the input file:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use feature 'say';
    use ntheory ":all";

# open filehandle log.txt
open (my $LOG, '>>', 'log.txt');
# select new filehandle
select $LOG;

    perl -Mntheory=:all -nE "chomp; say next_prime($_);" filenumber1.txt
```

primenumbers.pl is in the same directory as filenumbers.txt and something is wrong when I run the script and I do not know what:

C:\Users\Guest\Documents\Prime Numbers>perl primenumbers.pl

Bareword found where operator expected at primenumbers.pl line 7, near ""say next_prime($_);" filenumber1.txt"

```
    (Missing operator before filenumber1.txt?)
```

syntax error at primenumbers.pl line 7, near ""say next_prime($_);" filenumber1.txt"

Execution of primenumbers.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

I tried fixing it myself, but I only made matters worse, and there were more problems to fix. Does anyone know how to help me from here please on generating the output file "log.txt" without viewing the input file "filenumber1.txt"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a Windows shell command, not a Perl command!

Comment: What do you mean by "without viewing the input file"? You obviously can't transform a file's content without reading that content at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-n` switch to `perl` just wraps the code in `while (<>) { ... }`, so, to get a similar effect in your own program, just add the loop yourself (untested code; may contain errors):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use ntheory ":all";

# open filehandle log.txt
open (my $LOG, '>>', 'log.txt');
# select new filehandle
select $LOG;

while (<>) {
  chomp; say next_prime($_);
}
```

Run this with

```
primenumbers.pl filenumber1.txt
```

and you should be set.